# Determine the Ring End(G) for each abelian Group G

Tags: linear-algebra

Well here is the confusing question I have gotten from the professor. 
Determine the Ring End(G) for each abelian Group G from the previous exercice.
I found this 
https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/the-set-of-all-endomorphisms-of-an-abelian-group-is-a-ring-under-pointwise-addition-and-composition/
But i do not know if it helps with my question. Here are all the Groups of the previos exercice. 
[image: Groups]

Comment: A first step would be to figure out what the endomorphisms are. Note that all these groups are cyclic, so an endomorphism is uniquely determined by what it does to a generator.

Comment: @Tobias Well i understand how to do it with the multiplication It would be all the identities + the others, but how do i do it with the addition, as it is not determined

Comment: University of Zurich first semester? ;)

Comment: @TheGeekGreek yep ;)

Answer (score 1):

To simplify notation, note that your groups are $\mathbb Z_n $, with $n=2,3,4$. For the endomorphisms to form a ring, as your link says, one uses pointwise addition and composition as the operations. Of course, as is customary, here one uses additive notation for the group operation.

A homomorphism  $\phi:\mathbb Z_n\to\mathbb Z_n $ is determined by its action on the generator $1$ (that would be $f $ in the three groups you have). So there are $n $ of them, say $\phi_0,\ldots,\phi_{n-1} $ where $\phi_k (1)=k$. That is, $\phi_k (x)=kx $ with the cyclic addition of $\mathbb Z_n $.

Now note that $$(\phi_k+\phi_h)(x)=\phi_k (x)+\phi_h (x)=kx+hx=(k+h)x=\phi_{k+h}(x )$$
and
$$
\phi_k\circ\phi_h (x)=k (hx)=(kh)x=\phi_{kh}(x). $$
In other words, the map $\alpha:\mathbb Z_n\to\text {End}(G) $ given by $\alpha(k)=\phi_k$ is a ring homomorphism.  It is clearly onto, and if $\alpha (k)=0$ then $kx=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb Z_n $, so $k=0$; so it is also one-to-one.

In summary, the ring $\text {End}(\mathbb Z_n) $ is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb Z_n $.

Comment: Would that mean all the automorphisms of my groups would be units in the ring?

Comment: Of course. An automorphism has an inverse. Concretely, the automorphisms are precisely those $\phi_k$ with $k$ coprime with $n$.